# SQL Query to show nearest data to specific event

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to write a MySQL query that will return the nearest data which Actor = 210 for in terms E_id = 3.

This is my original table:

```
Session              Player  E_id  Time                     Actor  PosX  PosY  index
-------------------  ------  ----  -----------------------  -----  ----  ----  -----
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    906   466   6
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    342   540   7
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  31     812   244   8
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    248   614   9
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  21     342   688   10
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  49     812   170   11
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  50     248   466   12
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    718   318   13
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  52     154   466   14
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  211    499   250   15
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   3     01-11-2012 08:56:40.63   208    510   414   16
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    248   466   17
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   15    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  20     718   318   18
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  52     154   466   19
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  11     499   250   20
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   3     01-11-2012 08:56:40.63   208    510   414   21
```

If I fire query

```
select * from table where E_id = 3 or Actor = 210;
```

I get this result

```
Session              Player  E_id  Time                     Actor  PosX  PosY  index
-------------------  ------  ----  -----------------------  -----  ----  ----  -----
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    906   466   6
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    342   540   7
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    248   614   9
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    718   318   13
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   3     01-11-2012 08:56:40.63   208    510   414   16
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   17    01-11-2012 08:56:38.323  210    248   466   17
23131885ccc560bb6c8  10125   3     01-11-2012 08:56:40.63   208    510   414   21
```

**expected Result is:**
 row with index no 13 for row index no 16 and 
 row with index no 17 for row index no 21

Index 16 and 21 both **e_id** is **3**

Comment: what do you mean by closest

Comment: @ShivaKomuravelly nearest data which actor = 210

Comment: @Nileshpatel - can you please post your expected result?

Comment: @Nileshpatel If it is oracle then I could tell this solution: First sort them according to indexes and get the lead and lag value compare them and use whatever needed. Basically lead will give you the row above result and lag will give you the next row result.

Comment: @ShivaKomuravelly it is MYSQL by the way this is sample code i have lot of data like this type not only two row of e_id = 3

Comment: *How* did you determine that index 13 is closest to index 16, and that index 17 is closest to index 21?  I'm guessing it has something to do with `PosX` and `PosY`, but it really isn't clear from your question.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Nileshpatel if you enter Actor=210 then you must get row with index=16 as result right?

Comment: The question is what his input parameters are. I assume that they are Actor, E_ID and Index. For given E_ID and Index he wants to find a row with the specified Actor and closest index distance to the given input index

Comment: @FathahRehmanP no  i need to found if e_id = 3 then which is closest data which actor is 210 so when roe with index 16 i get row with index 13 as result

Comment: @Nileshpatel - i think answer you want is simple. But i cant understand your question properly

Comment: thanks a lot all of u i get my ans by @eggyal example  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87f91/44   it was so simple when i get final query :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i get my ans by @eggyal example [Solutution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87f91/44) it was so simple when i get final query

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is E_ID, Index and Actor. Index seems to be a unique column so you don't need E_ID.

This query will find closest (by index distance). But it will only look for rows with lower index (up).

```
select   *
from     your_tbl
where 16 - `index` >= 0 and Actor = 210
order by 16 - `index`
limit 1
```

16 gives you 13 and 21 gives 17

and there is another query that doesn't have the limitation of looking only up. It will find the closest index:

```
select   *
from     your_tbl
where Actor = 210
order by abs(21 - `index`)
limit 1
```

I give two queries because I don't understand what nearest means in the question. If it's nearest in terms of index distance abs(index1 - index2) then for 16 17 is as good result as 13 since they both have Actor = 210 and they are adjacent

Comment: i have not any specific distance in which i get actor is 210. i need to found if e_id = 3 then which is closest data which actor is 210 index is auto increment.

Comment: You said for index 16 you want to get index 13. Replace @your_index with 16 and the query will return the row with index 13

Comment: it is foe example row of index 13 is result for row of index 16

Comment: so that's right. When @your_index = 16, it will return row with index 13

Comment: your_index will not get to the results because his input index never has Actor=210. I tested my example in MS SQL and it worked as expected. I don't know what you are talking about :) and also what is the right answer?

Comment: I [don't have a clue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351745/sql-query-to-show-nearest-data-to-specific-event#comment19952892_14351745) what the question is, so I'm not even going to begin guessing at the answer.

Comment: @eggyal in your Fiddle example we get result row with 17 which is for row with index 21

Comment: @Nileshpatel: Quite.  Yet my input was 16.  This answer doesn't seem to do what you want (whatever that is).

Comment: @eggyal if you change your input 16 to 21 and u get same ans

Comment: I think Nilesh doesn't want to get rows below his input index. That's why I removed abs from the query

Comment: @eggyal how about a union with the two different wehre claueses? one for actor = 210 and the other for ed_id = 3? :) And looking at the indices, 16, 17, 21 are in incrementing order. So we could just pick up the certain conditioned max as well..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-dynamic answer. That means using a `union` and it's not the best. (Credit to eggyal for the sqlfiddle)

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87f91/77)

Query:

```
select   session, player, e_id,
time, actor, max(`index`)
from     your_tbl
where    Actor = 210
union
select   session, player, e_id,
time, actor, `index`
from     your_tbl
where    e_id = 3
;

|             SESSION | PLAYER | E_ID |                      TIME | ACTOR | MAX(`INDEX`) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 23131885ccc560bb6c8 |  10125 |   17 | January, 11 2012 08:56:38 |   210 |           17 |
| 23131885ccc560bb6c8 |  10125 |    3 | January, 11 2012 08:56:40 |   208 |           16 |
| 23131885ccc560bb6c8 |  10125 |    3 | January, 11 2012 08:56:40 |   208 |           21 |
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is the test that it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a58f2/50/4)

I dont really know if the 3rd or statement is really needed but thats if your application might use it as an especial case, you can remove it as you wish. If you want to delete the extra row i used, instead of **select *** Just after the variable assignments, change it to:

```
select `Session`, `Player`, `E_id`, `Time`, `Actor`, `PosX`, `PosY`, `index` ...
```

I didnt include that because the [ ` ] are not always welcome in PHP

```
 set @i = 0; 
    set @j = 0; 
    set @k = 0;
    set @l = 0;

    select * from (select *, @i:=@i+1 as myrow from your_tbl where E_id = 3 or Actor=210) as tb1 
    where myrow in
    (select myrow2-1 from 
    (select *, @j:=@j+1 as myrow2 from your_tbl where E_id = 3 or Actor=210) as tb2 
         where E_id=3) or myrow in
    (select myrow3+1 from 
    (select *, @k:=@k+1 as myrow3 from your_tbl where E_id = 3 or Actor=210) as tb3 
         where E_id=3) or myrow in
    (select myrow4 from 
    (select *, @l:=@l+1 as myrow4 from your_tbl where E_id = 3 or Actor=210) as tb4 
         where E_id=3)
```